# id of dynamically created button undefined

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamically created buttons:

```
<input type='button' id='remove_"+ii+"' class='removeItem' value='remove'>
```

the value of ii is irrelevant.

I am trying to listen for any of these buttons to be clicked and do something:

```
$(document).on('click',$('.removeItem'),function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

however, the alert is giving me "undefined".  At the very least i would expect to see "remove_"..

what am i missing?

Comment: `$(document).on('click',$('.removeItem'),function(){` should be `$(document).on('click','.removeItem',function(){` ... should not use `$('.removeItem')`

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the way you are registering the event handler. In your case you are passing a jQuery object as the second parameter while you are trying to use event delegation.

For event delegation you need to pass a string selector as the second param to `.on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeItem',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wkcj2s0r/)

Why?
Because [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method allows to pass a object as its parameter, which will be passed to the handler in the `event.data` property, so your handler instead of using event delegation is adding an handler to the `document` object with event data as a jQuery object. So `this` inside the handler is referring to the `document` object which does not have the `id` property

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wkcj2s0r/2/)

Comment: Was about to post this. JSFiddle to prove he's correct over at http://jsfiddle.net/d9hpxnre/